# Problem while trying to merge two columns of two different dataframes?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, merge

I am currently facing a problem that I don't seem to be able to solve with regards to handling and manipulating dataframes using Pandas.

To give you an idea of the dataframes I'm talking about and that you'll see in my code:

[image]
[image]
[image]

I’m trying to change the words found in column ‘exercise’ of the dataset ‘data’ with the words found in column ‘name’ of the dataset ‘exercise’.

For example, the acronym ‘Dl’ in the exercise column of the ‘data’ dataset should be changed into ‘Dead lifts’ found in the ‘name’ column of the ‘exercise’ dataset.

I have tried many methods but all have seemed to fail. I receive the same error every time.

Here is my code with the methods I tried:

```
### Method 1 ###

# Rename Name Column in 'exercise'
exercise = exercise.rename(columns={'label': 'exercise'})

# Merge Exercise Columns in 'exercise' and in 'data'
data = pd.merge(data, exercise, how = 'left', on='exercise')

### Method 2 ###
data.merge(exercise, left_on='exercise', right_on='label')

### Method 3 ###

data['exercise'] = data['exercise'].astype('category')
EXERCISELIST = exercise['name'].copy().to_list()
data['exercise'].cat.rename_categories(new_categories = EXERCISELIST, inplace = True)
                
### Same Error, New dataset ###

# Rename Name Column in 'area'
area = area.rename(columns={'description': 'area'})

# Merge Exercise Columns in 'exercise' and in 'data'
data = pd.merge(data, area, how = 'left', on = 'area')
```

This is the error I get:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "---", line 232, in 
> data.to_frame().merge(exercise, left_on='exercise', right_on='label')
>
> File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 8192, in merge
> return merge(
>
> File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/reshape/merge.py", line 74, in merge
> op = _MergeOperation(
>
> File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/reshape/merge.py", line 668, in *init*
> ) = self._get_merge_keys()
>
> File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/reshape/merge.py", line 1046, in _get_merge_keys
> left_keys.append(left._get_label_or_level_values(lk))
>
> File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 1683, in _get_label_or_level_values
> raise KeyError(key)
>
> KeyError: 'exercise'

Is someone able to help me with this? Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Call me crazy, but the line of code causing the error in the traceback doesn't seem to be in the code samples you submitted.

Comment: Also, I see you are using Python 3.9. I would double check if 3.9 is supported with pandas yet.

Comment: On the data `dataframe`, run this, and copy-paste the results: `print(data.columns)`

Comment: it's just a `merge()` between the three data frames. A classic join

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. merge, then drop and rename columns between **data** and **area**
2. merge, then drop and rename columns between step 1 and **exercise**

```
area = pd.DataFrame({"arealabel":["AGI","BAL"],
                    "description":["Agility","Balance"]})
exercise = pd.DataFrame({"description":["Jump rope","Dead lifts"],
                        "label":["Jr","Dl"]})
data = pd.DataFrame({"exercise":["Dl","Dl"],
                    "area":["AGI","BAL"],
                    "level":[0,3]})

(data.merge(area, left_on="area", right_on="arealabel")
 .drop(columns=["arealabel","area"])
 .rename(columns={"description":"area"})
 .merge(exercise, left_on="exercise", right_on="label")
 .drop(columns=["exercise","label"])
 .rename(columns={"description":"exercise"})
)
```

|  | level | area | exercise |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | Agility | Dead lifts |
| 1 | 3 | Balance | Dead lifts |